# SparkSQL select error for some fields

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark 1.3.1, in python, I have something like these :

```
t1=sqlCtx.createDataFrame(sizes, ["id", "sum"]) 

t1.registerTempTable("t1")

t1.take(1) <-- will show [Row(id=u'5b9a9171fde001c3d9b', sum=5)]
```

Now I can do `sqlCtx.sql("select id from t1")`

but I can't access "sum", when I do `sqlCtx.sql("select sum from t1")`, it will generate the following error :

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o99.sql.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.12] failure: ``('' expected but 
`from' found
select sum from t1
       ^
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In most SQL dialects, `SUM` is a reserved keyword that's used as a function in aggregate statements (for example, something like `SELECT SUM(foo) FROM bar WHERE foo > 3`). That means that `SUM` alone is an invalid expression, because the SQL parser expects a column as a parameter that should be aggregated.

To indicate that you are referring to a *column* named `sum` and not the `sum` function, try to escape your column name with backticks:

```
sqlCtx.sql("select `sum` from t1")
```

Comment: Ah!!  I really wanted to kick myself, I wasted about 2 hours trying to figure out the problem.  Thanks, it works now.

Comment: Happy to help. Feel free to accept the answer if it answered your question.